# JModelLegacy $model->setState('list.limit', 6); not limit list

Tags: joomla-3.x, jmodel

Am using `JModelLegacy` to get records , everthing works fine . however when setting limit with `$model->setState('list.limit', 6);` its not limiting the records below is my code :

```
      $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => false));
      $appParams = JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();
      $model->setState('params', $appParams);
      $model->setState('filter.category_id',$cat_id ); //change that to your Category ID
       $model->setState('list.limit', 6);
      $model->setState('list.ordering', 'hits');
      $model->setState('list.direction', 'ASC');
      $items = $model->getItems();
```

Comment: List.limit only limits the amount of items per page used by the pagination. If you want to retrieve only 6 records you have to adjust your SQL-Query

Comment: if you are adding state variables like that shouldn't you be using:

    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $app->setUserState('list.limit',6);

Instead of trying to set a state through the model?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect in the context this is being used, you might want to put ignore_request to true?

I believe ContentModelArticles::getItems calls ContentModelArticles::populateState (through ContentModelArticles::getListQuery which in turn call ContentModelArticles::getState) which in turn run the code

```
$value = $app->input->get('limit', $app->get('list_limit', 0), 'uint');
$this->setState('list.limit', $value);
```

which sets the limit based on $app->get('list_limit', 0) since 'limit' is likely not passed via request.

Comment: I also think it's the ignore_request. Try $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => **true**));